# I want to generate a report monthly

Tags: sql, oracle

--query--

```
select count(*)
    from TOKEN
    where CODE = xxx
      and createdDatetime >=trunc(sysdate);
```

--Result--

```
Count(*)
72
```

Currently I am using a monitoring tool that automatically run every day and gets the total count for whole day. Now I want to run a query that will automatically count the data for the whole month without changing the query every month.

Comment: Please add some sample data and needed result

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get

Comment: Add sample report. And state what exactly you want to get

Comment: I suspect this will end up just being a case of pointing you at the add_months function, but it does need more clarity to be able to provide an answer that we can be confident is correct.

Comment: @WhiteLeoming - do you mean from today - 1 month, or is it to be the last full month? We need more specific details ideally.

Comment: How can we understand the result without knowing your data? Please try to build a small example, explaining the result you need for that data. Also, please edit the question instead of adding comments .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A condition you use:

```
and createdDatetime >= trunc(sysdate);
```

returns data for *today*, as `TRUNC`, applied to `SYSDATE`, gives "very first moments of today".

But, if you adjust it a little bit and truncate `SYSDATE` to a month, you'd get the first day of current month, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2    trunc(sysdate) today,
  3    trunc(sysdate, 'mm') this_month
  4  from dual;

TODAY               THIS_MONTH
------------------- -------------------
23.07.2018 00:00:00 01.07.2018 00:00:00

SQL>
```

so you'd, finally, use

```
and createdDatetime >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, 
Wow, I've been looking for this 'mm' for 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you prefer by telling "the whole month" ;

The period past since one-month before :

```
 select count(1)
   from TOKEN
  where CODE = 'xxx'
    and months_between(trunc(sysdate),createdDatetime)<=1;
```

From the beginning of the current month :

```
 select count(1)
   from TOKEN
  where CODE = 'xxx'
    and to_char(createdDatetime,'yyyymm') = to_char(trunc(sysdate),'yyyymm');
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fee8cc/3)